# How can I take the value from local storage and put it in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code.

```js
(function Pull_Data_From_Storage(){     
    const text_field_data = document.getElementById("text_field").value;
    const stored_text_data = localStorage.getItem("TEXT735");
    text_field_data = stored_text_data;
})();
```

I am trying to get a `localStorage` value and get it in a html element.

Comment: var text_field_data = document.getElementById('text_field').value; text_field_data.innerHTML = stored_text_data;

Comment: Can you explain what are you looking for? Do you want to display an item from local storage inside html element?

Comment: Yes. I want to put the value in local storage inside a html element when the page first loads.

Comment: When I run the program it does not show the values from local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the value stored in `localStorage` inside a `textarea` element, you can assign it's value once you have the `stored_text_data` as below.

```js
(function Pull_Data_From_Storage() { 
  const stored_text_data = localStorage.getItem("TEXT735");
  document.getElementById("text_field").value= stored_text_data;
})();
```

Comment: I have tried this too and it does not work

Comment: @CodeShow What is your `text_field` element? Is it a `div`?

Comment: No it is the textarea element

Comment: So you want the value to be inside the `textarea` element right? I'll edit the answer

Comment: @CodeShow Welcome. Also please consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful

Comment: Sorry Rifky when I try to do that it tells me that I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. But it also tells me that my feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @CodeShow That's fine. Glad it helped your problem

Comment: Thank you @CodeShow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById("text_field").innerHTML` and set value

```
function Pull_Data_From_Storage(){ 
    const text_field_data = document.getElementById("text_field").innerHTML;
    const stored_text_data = localStorage.getItem("TEXT735");
    text_field_data = stored_text_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you store the value in a variable, changing the value of that variable won't change that property on the element. You need to directly set the value on the text field instead.

```
document.getElementById("text_field").value = stored_text_data;
```